# How can create partitions and aggregates against them on Trino?

Tags: sql, window-functions, trino

I have a dataset with a unique identifier (ID) and timestamp date stored in trino table.

| UID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 10:28 |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 18:28 |
| 2 | 2023-09-02 08:15 |
| 2 | 2023-09-02 18:30 |

I want to create a window with specfic date range for example, from **18:28** of **09/01** to **18:30** of **09/02**. For the subsequent dates, the desired resulting data will be aggregated and grouped as the following

| Unique Count | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 |
| 2 | 2023-09-02 |

I heard that window function can partition the data to specfic range chunks and apply window functions to it? Will it work? Or any other way to approach this problem?

I tried executing without window, but resulted in receiving no data, or incorrect data.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT UID) AS count,
  timestamp AS time
FROM
  (SELECT UID, timestamp 
  FROM logs_based_on_time
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN (timetsamp - INTERVAL '1' DAY) + INTERVAL '18' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
  AND (timestamp- INTERVAL '1' DAY) + INTERVAL '1' DAY + INTERVAL '18' HOUR + INTERVAL '30' MINUTE + INTERVAL '1' DAY) AS t
GROUP BY
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.time) AS day,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.time) AS hour
ORDER BY
  EXTRACT(DAY FROM t.time) AS day,
  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM t.time) AS hour
```

Any other way to appraoch this problem? Should i consider trying window functions?